# Downloading files from urls using multithreading

Tags: multithreading, curl, coldfusion

I need to download a list of excel files from urls and save them in a folder. (There can be up to 200 files or so.) I started off with the following code to loop and download each file:

```
<cfloop query="idsToDownload">
    <cfset fileURL = "https://myLink/#downloadID#" /><!--- link to an xlsx file --->
    <cfexecute name="curl" arguments = "#fileURL# -k" timeout="10" outputFile="#downloadID#.xlsx" />
</cfloop>
```

This downloads each file and saves them in the coldfusion temp directory. (For now, just for testing - eventually we will decide where we want them stored and update `outputFile` with the path.) This works well, except that eventually the cfloop time limit is reached (after around 30 file downloads). But anyway, we really want to start a thread for each download to maximize efficiency. So I added in a cfthread tag within the loop (Disclaimer: I'm new to cfthreading):

```
<cfloop query="idsToDownload">
    <cfthread name="download_#downloadID#" action="run">
        <cfset fileURL = "https://myLink/#downloadID#" />
        <cfexecute name="curl" arguments = "#fileURL# -k" timeout="10" outputFile="#downloadID#.xlsx" />
    </cfthread>
</cfloop>
```

I would assume that this would execute the same as before, except that each download would run in an asynchronous thread. However, when I run this, nothing happens at all. I don't get any errors on the page, but no files show up in the ColdFusion temp file (as it does with the simple unthreaded cfloop). What is wrong with this code?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried a single thread with a single download, and it worked correctly:

```
<cfthread name="downloadFile" action="run">
    <cfset fileURL = "https://myLink/123" />
    <cfexecute name="curl" arguments = "#fileURL# -k" timeout="10" outputFile="123.xlsx" />
</cfthread>
```

So it seem there's something wrong with the cfloop/cfthread combination...

Comment: Just because you don't get errors on the page does not mean that none occurred.  You only see errors generated from the main thread.  To check for errors on the other threads, look at your exception log.

Comment: @DanBracuk - I understand that there are probably errors, I just wasn't sure what they were and how to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may want a different approach to downloading hundreds of files. Thread-per-file will only scale so high before the target server will likely stop responding or block you (if it's not under your control). Also, if you're using cURL, then you're spawning a child process for each thread, so it's quite resource-heavy.

Instead I'd create a thread-pool and distribute work between them. Create N threads and give each thread a list of files to download. Each thread will work through the list and you can easily tune N to give you the best performance/resource usage trade-off.

The possible potential downside of the approach above is that if one list of files is much faster to download than others, it'll then end early and the remaining work will be performed by fewer threads. You could implement a single work-tracker that each thread calls to pick up the next file to download. As long as its getNextFile() method is suitably synchronized, that'll keep all N threads working until there's on more work to be done.

Also, consider not using cURL if your download is as simple as the example looks. Consider CFHTTP or one of the java HTTP Client libraries as you won't have to spawn a process per download.

**EDIT**
With regard to getting the existing code running, I was able to build a corresponding example, which appears to perform ok (CF10/OSX):

```
Thread test...<br/>
<cfloop from="1" to="3" index="i">  
    <cfoutput>Starting #i# <br/></cfoutput><cfflush>
    <cfthread action="run" name="dl-thread-#i#" urlNumber="#i#">
        <cflog log="Application" text="#urlNumber#">
    <cfexecute name="/opt/local/bin/curl" arguments="https://www.google.co.uk/?q=#urlNumber#" outputfile="#GetTemplatePath()##urlNumber#.html" errorFile="#GetTemplatePath()##urlNumber#.html.err">
    <!--- alternatively....
    <cfhttp url="https://www.google.co.uk/?q=#urlNumber#" file="#urlNumber#.html" path="#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetTemplatePath())#" method="get" />
    --->
    </cfexecute>
</cfthread> 
</cfloop>
Done....
```

The only real difference I can see is that I'm passing parameters to the thread explicitly and allowing the thread code to use those parameters to assemble the URL (see the urlNumber attribute). Before I did that I saw very odd results: I got files written for values 2-4, not 1-3.

I'd make sure any data the thread needs is explicitly passed in. Also, the docs on cfexecute state that the name attribute needs to be an absolute path, including extension, but your code seems to be working ok without?

I've included a commented out example of using `<cfhttp>` to achieve the same thing as curl. Launching any external process many hundreds of times will almost certainly not scale. Adapting the example above to split up a list and each work on that list should be straightforward.

**EDIT 2**
The snippet below implements dividing up workload between a configurable number of threads:

```
Thread test...<br/>
<cfscript>
    urlCount=100;
    threads=5;
    urls=[];

    //utility function to split an array into a set of equal arrays
    function ArrayDivide(arr,divisor){
        divided=[];
        for(i=1;i<=divisor;i++){
            divided[i]=[];
        }
        for(i=1;i<=ArrayLen(arr);i++){
            ArrayAppend(divided[(i%divisor)+1],arr[i]);
            WriteOutput((i%divisor)+1 & "<br>");
        }
        return divided;
    }

    //Create a set of dummy URLs to test against
    //sleep.cfm waits for as long as it's asked to in order to simulate downloads taking a bit of time
    for(i=1;i<=urlCount;i++){
        urls[i]="http://localhost:8500/sleep.cfm?duration="&(i*50);
    }

    urlLists=ArrayDivide(urls,threads);

</cfscript>

<cfloop from="1" to="#threads#" index="i">  
    <cfoutput>Starting #i# <br/></cfoutput><cfflush>
    <cflog log="Application" text="#i# spawn">
    <cfthread action="run" name="dl-thread-#i#" urlList="#urlLists[i]#" threadNumber="#i#">
        <cflog log="Application" text="#threadNumber# start">
        <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(urlList)#" index="j">
            <cfhttp url="#urlList[j]#" file="#threadNumber#_#j#.html" path="#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetTemplatePath())#" method="get" />
        </cfloop>
        <cflog log="Application" text="#urlNumber# end">
</cfthread> 

</cfloop>
Done....
```

Comment: Doesn't CFHTTP spawn new threads for each call as well? Also, much as this answer offers helpful alternatives, it doesn't actually fix my code :) Any ideas?

Comment: Also, would Wget be less overhead than cURL?

Comment: thanks for the update! I'm going to work on all the options. I didn't realize you're supposed to pass the data to the thread. If I get it working properly using your tips I'll accept the answer

Comment: This worked! The error was due to the data not being explicitly passed into the thread. Thank you!

Comment: btw, I did end up modeling my code on the snippet in Edit 2, to implement a "thread pool", so thank you! (I know this was a while ago, but I just realized that I never updated)

Comment: Thanks for updating, I really appreciate knowing that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think You need to sleep the thread for a small amount of time to make sure that code nested inside cfthread tag does not execute until after the **idsToDownload** loop has actually finished executing.

```
<cfloop query="idsToDownload">
<cfthread name="download_#downloadID#" action="run" downloadId="#idsToDownload.downloadId#" fileUrl="#idsToDownload.fileUrl#">
    <cfthread action="sleep" duration="500"/>
    <cfset fileURL = "https://myLink/#attributes.downloadID#" />
    <cfexecute name="curl" arguments = "#attributes.fileURL# -k" timeout="10" outputFile="#attributes.downloadID#.xlsx" />
</cfthread>
```

I am not sure this will work as i have never worked with curl. But let me know what happens.

Comment: Isn't that the point? I want to just set off each thread to run asynchronously

Comment: Thread has asynchronous nature so they will run independently. The 500 milliseconds is only to ensure that the logic of the CFThread might take longer than an individual iteration of the CFLoop. As long as it takes just a little bit longer - which may be due to processing power or simply due to thread queuing - then you'll run into the some problem.
I have also updated code to make it more correct. Please check.

Comment: @TusharBhaware you can also set the thread priority to high so that it will get priority while executing. by default it has normal priority.

Comment: I'm still not really understanding the logic of this - but I did try adding the code and it didn't help.

Comment: @froadie, I am sorry mate, it didn't worked. I am not great with words. To understand logic behind the code, please read [ben nadel's blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1897-using-cfthread-inside-a-coldfusion-query-loop.htm).